# Closest two values from certain value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the points `X` and `Y`. I need to find the `X` and `Y` point closest to the origin `(0, 0)`.

I am trying this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM `line` 
WHERE xi < yi and 0 < xi and 0 < yi and yi < xi
ORDER BY yi and xi  ASC 
Limit 100
```

But I am not getting the desired values.

Comment: A `where` clause with both `xi < yi` and `yi < xi` is never going to return a match.

Comment: But is does...  Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 299 total, Query took 0.0004 sec)
         SELECT *
         FROM `line` 
         WHERE xi < yi

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distance to the origin is given by `sqrt(xi^2 +yi^2)`.  Since a square root is strictly ascending, you can omit it for the purpose of ordering.  That gives:

```
SELECT *
FROM `line` 
ORDER BY xi*xi + yi*yi
Limit 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the distance `d = sqrt(x²+y²)` to get the nearest point from the origin

```
select x, y, sqrt(x*x + y*y) as distance
from `line` 
order by distance asc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT xi, yi, xi * xi + yi * yi As r2
FROM line
ORDER BY r2
```